how to write host predicate correctly in spring cloud gateway
I have spring cloud gateway + spring cloud eureka discovery server + 2 services
I want all requests from one of my services to be redirected to the second service, but in the discovery service I have several replicas of the first service, and in the host predicate (auth_login_route) I want to write not the exact address of my service, but its name, so that gateway takes the exact address from the discovery service
first service name = users.service
second service name = auth.service
spring gateway application.yml file ->
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway.service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      mvc:
        routes:
          - id: users_route
            uri: lb://users.service
            predicates:
              - Path=/users/**
          - id: auth_login_route
            uri: lb://auth.service
            predicates:
              - Host=**.users.service
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: 'true'
          lower-case-service-id: true

eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
    registerWithEureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    instance:
      preferIpAddress: true

I tried that, but I only got 400 exception in response

Is this a valid config ? cloud:
gateway:
mvc:

yes this is valid config, but I already found solution, I added service-name default header for requests in my first service, and tried to use header predicate and it is working
